# Updating tagname of a rootnode in xml using python

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, minidom

I have an xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<r:result>
  ...
</r:result>
```

And i wanted to know if it's possible to change a `rootElement` `tagName` from `r:result` to something else. I was trying to find such information in the `minidom` library but didn't find. 
Please point me into a method to use or a library, don't provide a solution, i just need a sugesstion.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at [ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html), which is a built-in XML-parsing library.

(The tag for *Minidom* says its use is not recommended, and points *ElementTree* instead. I've use *ElementTree* many times, and it generally works pretty well.)

In particular, you'll want to look at the [Modifying an XML File](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#modifying-an-xml-file) section.

You can manipulate the *XML Dom* in a variety of ways, removing nodes, adding them, changing attributes, etc.

Also note the warning in the doc about security issues when parsing unauthenticated data (this may or may not apply to your use case).